# In php, how to destroy the session variables

Tags: php, session

my problem is that the session variable did not get unset when running the below code.
what is wrong?

```
<?php  
 session_start();
 session_unset();
 //session_destroy();
 header("location: user_form.php");
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

You've not actually created a session you've started the session engine but not created a session variable.
If you have a session variable $_SESSION['userid'] for example then you can just unset that value or expire it or set its value to something that would fail your if clause for your header redirect.

Comment: If he is asking how to remove the $_SESSION variables, probably (I presume) that he already have them started from another page.

Comment: you would assume so but since he's not unsetting or destroying the specific variables created its no surprise its not unsetting them.

Comment: Ahh, I've misunderstood what you mean, sorry :) That's why I've suggested something like a foreach to unset the vars.

Comment: Your method is greate if you want to unset all potential sessions but if he's looking to unset one specific session or is using sessions as a method of login security etc its not so good.

Answer (score 3):

Usually I do something like:

```
<?php  
 session_start();

 if(!empty($_SESSION) && is_array($_SESSION)) {
     foreach($_SESSION as $sessionKey => $sessionValue)
         session_unset($_SESSION[$sessionKey]);
 }

 session_destroy();

 header("Location: user_form.php");
?>
```

Comment: Edited, thanks @user1615903. Corrected the key in the array when unsetting.

Answer (score 1):

Try this syntax (use a variable name in unset):

```
 <?php
    session_start();
    if(isset($_SESSION['views']))
      unset($_SESSION['views']);
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you already have variables within your session set, otherwise there would be nothing to "unset".

With session_unset the session itself would still exist, as it's just the equivalent of doing:

```
$_SESSION = array();
```

Unless of course you're using PHP 4.0.6 or below, then you would be expected to use:

```
unset ($_SESSION['varname']);
```

as per [**`session_unset`**](http://php.net/session_unset).

There isn't anything "wrong" with your code so to speak.